# TKinter and TTK Themes and Title frame

Tags: python, tkinter, themes

So I have a relatively decent application already built just using `tk` widgets and obviously it looks really basic. Basic squares and rectangles stacked on top of each other. I just now realized after the app being 80% done that there are themes and and other cool uses with `ttk`. I would really like to attempt to rework this application using ttk but I have some questions. These are some examples of the themes available found at https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes and I'm curious about how the title bars match the theme. When I attempted to test some of these themes the title bar generally stayed the same. Is there anyway to get the title bar to match the theme like in "breeze-dark" for example?

[image]

Comment: The title bar is not managed by Tkinter but by your desktop environment (DE) so you will have to change your DE theme if you want to match it to your ttk theme. For instance, Breeze is a theme in KDE and is also available in other DEs (XFCE, ...) in linux.

Comment: @j_4321 that is interesting I didn't realize that. Thank you, I'll give it a shot!